# Power Query Conditional Columns - Combine 2 values for 1 Line/Output

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

Is it possible to combine 2 values for 1 line/output for a Conditional Column? Below is an example.

Current, 2 Lines:

```
each if 
[source] = "Source" and [medium] = "Medium" and [medium-2] = "Paid Search" 
or [source] = "Source" and [medium] = "Medium" and [medium-2] = "cpc"
then ="Paid Search"
```

Desired, 1 Line - Combining both values for "medium-2" into 1 line:

```
each if
[source] = "Source" and [medium] = "Medium" and [medium-2] = "Paid Search" or "cpc"
then ="Paid Search"
```

Thanks for the help,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically,

```
([source] = "Source" and [medium] = "Medium" and [medium-2] = "Paid Search") or
([source] = "Source" and [medium] = "Medium" and [medium-2] = "cpc")
```

is equivalent to

```
[source] = "Source" and [medium] = "Medium" and
( [medium-2] = "Paid Search" or [medium-2] = "cpc" )
```

I.e.

```
( A && B && C ) || ( A && B && D ) = ( A && B ) && ( C || D )
```

---

If the question is more related to syntax, then I'd point out that

```
[medium-2] = "Paid Search" or [medium-2] = "cpc"
```

can be rewritten as

```
List.Contains( { "Paid Search", "cpc" }, [medium-2] )
```

which isn't much shorter unless you have more than two options.

Comment: That's it!! Thank you.